# Tensor Product: Closability

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

*This was a real question of mine.*

Given Hilbert spaces.

Then closability will be inherited on tensor products:
$$A,B\text{ closable}\implies A\otimes B\text{ closable}$$

For simple tensors this is clear as:
$$A\otimes B(\varphi_n\otimes\psi_n)\text{ cauchy}\implies A\varphi_n,B\psi_n\text{ cauchy}$$

But what about arbitrary tensors?

Comment: To clarify, you're asking if it's true, about the proof, or what?

Comment: @tomasz: Good that you ask: I ask for a proof. However, I got it meanwhile: Will post it in a minute. Alternative proofs are still heartly welcome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I got it meanwhile; answers are still heartly welcome!*

For densely-defined operators it holds:
$$A\text{ closable}\iff A^*\text{ densely defined}$$

But one has the inclusion:
$$A^*\otimes B^*\subseteq(A\otimes B)^*$$
So the result follows from denseness of the adjoint.

*(Note that this proof works only for densely defined operator.)*